# Scaffold only a subset of methods in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to generate a subset of methods in the controller using scaffold instead of the regular scaffold?

For example: Only create new and show?

I am using rails 3, ruby 1.9.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the default rails scaffold generator supports this in Rails 3.

However, this can be accomplished using the nifty-generators gem:

https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Answer (score 1):

In plain Rails3, you can do this when you generate the controller:

```
rails generate controller Artists new create
```

So, you could just generate the model, and then the controller, and get the overall functionality you were looking for.